Importing GeoTIFFs in GeoServer with Float32 type bands
I have a system where users can import GeoTiff files with float32 type. When importing these files into QGIS, the application automatically applies color enhancements using cumulative count cut with a certain percentage.
I followed this example  and was able to retrieve a special style that works for a specific GeoTiff file. However, I need the styling to be dynamic for different GeoTiff files. My idea is to preprocess all GeoTiffs with Python scripts and apply recreate bands before uploading them.
My question is, is this approach of preprocessing and styling GeoTiff files before uploading considered a good practice in the industry? Could this approach lead to any potential issues with GeoServer?

When you upload directly in QGIS you are serving the GeoTIFFs as data, but when you use GeoServer with SLD's you are serving them up as representations of data (WMS).  These aren't  comparable situations.  Comparable would be serving them through WCS.
